# select integer before a certain character

Tags: sql-server

hie am trying to select the integer value before the char C in my SQL database table which contains the information below.

```
240mm2 X 15C WIRING CABLE
150mm2 X 3C flex
10mm2 x 4C swa
```

so far i have used the query

```
 select left ('C',CHARINDEX ('C',product_name)) from product
```

and i get 'C' on my results which is correct. Now am stuck does anyone know how i can modify  the above select query to get a result which only lists the integers for eg

```
15
 3
 4
```

Comment: Is this really MySQL or do you actually mean MSSQL (SQL Server)? Charindex doesn't exist in MySQL as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this in SQL Server you could try the following:

```
Select Substring(product_name, 
                 PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',product_name) + 1, 
                 PATINDEX('%[0-9]C%',product_name) - PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',product_name)
                ) as num
from Product
```

This assumes that there is a space before the number and always a C after the number with no space.

It works out the starting point and then the length based on the start and end and performs a substring with the results.

Answer (score 3):

Two observations:  the integer before "C" has a space before it and there is no space between the integer and "C".

If these are generally true, then you can do what you want using `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(product_name, 'C', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 as thenumber
```

The `+ 0` simply converts the value to a number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of instring and substring.

First get the position of the C
Then substring till C

It goes like this:

```
SELECT INSTR('foobarbar', 'bar');
= 4
```

And then you select substring from 1 to 4.